# updating a column blanks from values within the table

Tags: mysql, updates

I want to update a table column where the field is blank with a zip code from within the column as the Name field is same for the 2 rows.

so the shipping zip blanks need to be filled with the same shipping zip where name is the same.

Thanks

[The attached is the table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6peB.png)

Comment: Try googling `sql fill the column with previous row value`, the first *four* results are SO answers.

Comment: I tried this query: update table s1
set s1.shipping_zip = (select shipping_zip from table where Name = Name); but it gives an error saying cant use the table name in from statement

Comment: if I try to use the previous row value it will also update the blank with the other values as the screenshot is a filtered columns based on some condition. the actual column is full with zipcodes and blanks and I want the blanks to be filled with a specific zipcodes based on name being same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide an actual table name. I will use `table_name` as a way to show you what to do. I am using the table_name twice, so each time I give it an **alias** (`m` & `f`). So that we can do compares

Slow answer

```
UPDATE table_name m
SET m.shipping_zip = 
   (SELECT f.shipping_zip 
    FROM table_name f 
    WHERE f.Name=m.Name and f.shipping_zip<>'')
WHERE m.shipping_zip = '';
```

Fast answer (but untested)

```
UPDATE table_name m, table_name f
SET m.shipping_zip = f.shipping_zip
WHERE m.Name=f.Name AND m.shipping_zip='' AND f.shipping_zip<>'';
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using two tables - m and f. I am trying to do this within a table, using the data from column where there are no blanks(zipcodes) and moving that data into the blank column

Comment: No, I am using one table but giving it two different names so that we can compare and act. This is a neat trick in SQL. You didn't provide a table name , so I put a generic table_name in there.

Comment: It throws an error code 1093, you cant specify target table m for update in from clause... did not work

Comment: Awesome thanks , this worked after I turned off the safe update mode

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this

```
update `table` t, (select * from `table`
where shipping_zip is not null and shipping_zip != '')q
set t.shipping_zip = q.shipping_zip
where t.Name = q.Name;
```

Comment: did sql allow you to use from "table" in the select statement?

Comment: Here "table" is the name of your table. Replace it with the actual table name. And I tried this exact query in a sample table. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: it throws me an error code 1175, saying you are using a safe update mode and tried to update a table without a where that uses a key column .. I wonder whats that all about

Comment: You need to turn off the safe update mode for this to work. Otherwise update and select from same table wont work.